# How to change the item per page count according to windows size

Tags: javascript

I have a list of items which initially shows 12 items per page, I wanted to implement some more responsiveness to my page. When i'm resizing the window size or for using differnt devices i need to show the items according to that window size.

I have tried to get current window siz using window.innerwidth by using ifelse for variation. How can i pass the count variable to my itemsPerPage.

Here is my JS Code. (Tried this after the suggestion frm the comment)

```
var detect = function (width) {
      var count;
      if (width < 576) {
           count = 6;
      } else if (width >= 576 && width < 768) {
            count = 8;
      } else if (width >= 768 && width < 992) {
            count = 12;
      } else if (width >= 992) {
            count = 16;
      }
  }

$(function () {
    $("#content")
        .flexiblePagination({
            //I wanted to change this itemperPage value according to my window size
            itemsPerPage: count,
            displayedPages: 4,
            itemSelector: "div.result:visible",
            pagingControlsContainer: "#pagingControls",
            showingInfoSelector: "#showingInfo",
            searchBox: { onClick: !0, onClickSelector: "#search" },
        })
        .getController().onPageClick = function (s, n) {
        console.log("You Clicked Page: " + s);
    };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
var width = window.innerWidth;
detect(width) $(window).resize(function() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    detect(width)
});
```

});

Its not working what's the issue here.

Comment: Anyone......???

Comment: simplest option would be to calculate `itemsPerPage` based on window size (width or height, please specify what's needed). However this will not be refreshed dynamically and will require page reload when window size changes. Example: `itemsPerPage: window.innerWidth < 1024 ? (window.innerWidth < 768 ? 6 : 8) : 12`

Comment: Is it possible to get this things done without refreshing the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `window.innerWidth` should be used to calculate `itemsPerPage`.

You have already created the `detect(width)` function to calculate it.

However it had an issue that `count` variable is declared inside `detect` function and is not visible (and can't be used) outside. The simplest way to use the result of `detect` function is to add `return` statement.

```
const detect = function (width) {
        let count;
        if (width < 576) {
            count = 6;
        } else if (width >= 576 && width < 768) {
            count = 8;
        } else if (width >= 768 && width < 992) {
            count = 12;
        } else if (width >= 992) {
            count = 16;
        }
        return count;
}
```

Now we can call `detect(window.innerWidth)` when we initialize pagination component to get corresponding `itemsPerPage`.

Let's move pagination setup into a separate function for re-use.

```
function setupPagination() {
    $("#content")
        .flexiblePagination({
            itemsPerPage: detect(window.innerWidth), // calculate using detect()
            displayedPages: 4,
            itemSelector: "div.result:visible",
            pagingControlsContainer: "#pagingControls",
            showingInfoSelector: "#showingInfo",
            searchBox: { onClick: !0, onClickSelector: "#search" },
        })
        .getController().onPageClick = function (s, n) {
        console.log("You Clicked Page: " + s);
    };
}
```

The `setupPagination` function needs to be called during initial load and when window is resized to update the settings.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setupPagination();
    
    $(window).resize(function () {
        setupPagination();
    });
});
```

However when testing this I've discovered that pagination plugin removes some items from `content` div when called. It's quite unpleasant but we can have backup of `content` div HTML (`$('#content').html()`) and restore it when window gets resized and we need to call pagination plugin again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const backup = $('#content').html(); // plugin kills content, keep backup
    setupPagination();
    
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('#content').html(backup); // restore content
        setupPagination();
    });
});
```

See working example bellow:

```js
const detect = function (width) {
        let count;
        if (width < 576) {
            count = 6;
        } else if (width >= 576 && width < 768) {
            count = 8;
        } else if (width >= 768 && width < 992) {
            count = 12;
        } else if (width >= 992) {
            count = 16;
        }
        return count;
}

function setupPagination() {
    $("#content")
        .flexiblePagination({
            itemsPerPage: detect(window.innerWidth), // calculate
            displayedPages: 4,
            itemSelector: "div.result:visible",
            pagingControlsContainer: "#pagingControls",
            showingInfoSelector: "#showingInfo",
            searchBox: { onClick: !0, onClickSelector: "#search" },
        })
        .getController().onPageClick = function (s, n) {
        console.log("You Clicked Page: " + s);
    };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    const backup = $('#content').html(); // plugin kills content, keep backup
    setupPagination();
    
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('#content').html(backup); // restore content
        setupPagination();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/content-paginator-flexiblepaginationjs/Flexible.Pagination.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search">
<div id="content">
    <div>
    <div class="result">Item 1</div>
    <div class="result">Item 2</div>
    <div class="result">Item 3</div>
    <div class="result">Item 4</div>
    <div class="result">Item 5</div>
    <div class="result">Item 6</div>
    <div class="result">Item 7</div>
    <div class="result">Item 8</div>
    <div class="result">Item 9</div>
    <div class="result">Item 10</div>
    <div class="result">Item 11</div>
    <div class="result">Item 12</div>
    <div class="result">Item 13</div>
    <div class="result">Item 14</div>
    <div class="result">Item 15</div>
    <div class="result">Item 16</div>
    <div class="result">Item 17</div>
    <div class="result">Item 18</div>
    <div class="result">Item 19</div>
    <div class="result">Item 20</div>
    <div class="result">Item 21</div>
    <div class="result">Item 22</div>
    <div class="result">Item 23</div>
    <div class="result">Item 24</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pagingControls"></div>
<div id="showingInfo"><div>
```

Comment: It's great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`window.innerHeight` contains the window's height (in pixels, someone correct me if I am wrong). You can then divide this by the maximum height of one of the content containers' sizes.

If you want to keep updating it, you can create an interval to do this.